# Does Docker give RAM extra mileage?

Tags: performance, docker, virtualization, ram

[According](https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/) | [to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) | [countless](https://events.yandex.com/events/yac/2013/talks/14/) | [sources](http://www.unixmen.com/docker-lightweight-virtualization-linux-containers/), Docker provides ultra-lightweight virtualization by sharing system resources across containers, instead of allocating copies of those resources per container.

I've even read articles where it is boasted that you could "*run dozens, even hundreds of containers on the same VM.*"

But if my app requires 2GB RAM to run, and the underlying physical machine has only 8GB RAM on it, I would normally only be able to run 3 instances of my app on it (leaving ~2GB for system memory, utilities, etc.).

Does Docker do some kind of magic with RAM, allowing me to *actually* run **dozens** of containers, each one allocated 2GB RAM, but somehow sharing unused memory under the hood?

Or are those statements more media hype than anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people talk about running *"dozens or hundreds of containers"* they are normally thinking about microservices; small applications that do a specific task. Each of these may have memory usage measured in KBs rather than MBs, and probably not GBs, and as such there is no reason a decent machine couldn't run dozens or hundreds of them.

There is actually a [competition](http://blog.hypriot.com/post/dockercon2015/) (I think it's on-going) to get as many containers as possible running on a Raspberry Pi. The result currently stands at over a thousand, but admittedly these containers won't be running a real-life application.

Regarding memory, the answer is "it's complicated". If you're using the AUFS or Overlay driver, containers with the same base image should be able to share "memory pages"; meaning shared libraries shouldn't need to get loaded twice for two containers. This isn't something special though; normal processes running on the host will work the same way.

At the end of the day, containers are little more than isolated processes. We can easily run dozens or hundreds of processes on a host, so it's not unfeasible to run dozens or hundreds of containers.

Answer (score 0):

A Docker container only consumes the resources that it needs as it needs them.  So yes you could literally run hundreds of machines on one box as long as they are not all actively consuming your resources.  That is what makes Docker unique; the fact that a container will use what resources it can and then release them making them available for another container on the same host.  It is best practice to let the container and Docker handle allocating resources instead of doing a hard assign of them.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative would be a virtual machine.  Each virtual machine that you run has to run a full linux kernal, and the host OS will hold a chunk of memory aside for the virtualized environment.  This means that you can really only run a couple VMs on all but the heaviest duty hardware.

A container does NOT run a kernel- it just runs a single process (plus sub processes).  This means that you can run as many processes in containers as you could if you were running those same processes without containers- each thinks it is running on a separate machine, but they all just show up as processes on the host kernel.

There is no magic that will make you able to use RAM dozens of times over.  But you can pack smaller processes in together a LOT tighter than you could using virtual machines for seperation.